# Python game logic - Pokemon-like type differences

Tags: python, logic

I can't really wrap my head around this. I'm making this Text-based Adventure game and I want to implement these type differences (Water > Fire, Fire > Grass) into the game for more specialised attacks and mechanics. But how exactly could I code this in?

Comment: If you're using object oriented programming, 4 parent classes representing the elements, have them deal bonus damage to pokemon of their target type etc. Then have each pokemon inherit it's type.

Comment: hmm, I indeed am using OOP. Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use inequalities on objects like you say (`water > fire`), then you can implement the magic methods on your classes, such as `__lt__`. See the docs here (`https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__`)

However, this probably isn't the best way to do it. What you could do, for example, is write a boolean function that implements this "is stronger than" relation. This function could be backed by a simple dictionary from type to set of types, e.g.:

```
type_data = {'water': {fire}, 'fire': {grass}}

def is_stronger(x, y):
  return y.type in type_data[x.type]
```